# Problems with text formatting

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to finish my program.The program will ask for `n` employees from a company, then the `name`, `salary`and `sale of the month`. The output will show the previous information plus the `comission`, `net salary` and a `total` of each one of them.

For better understanding, this would be the output:

```
Name               Salary    Sale of the month           Comission    Net salary 
Elena Gomez       2000.00              1000.00              35.00       2035.00
Elle Johns        4000.00              1345.00              60.53       4060.53 
Stefan Cox        3200.00              4000.00             216.00       3416.00 
Total             9200.00              6345.00             311.53       9511.53 

Employee with upper comission: Stefan Cox 216.00
Employee with lower comission: Elena Gomez 35.0
Employee with upper net salary: Elle Johns 4060.53
Employee with lower net salary: Elena Gomez 2035.00

Employees with sales upper than the prom (US$2115)

Name               Salary    Sale of the month           Comission    Net salary
Stefan Cox        3200.00              4000.00             216.00       3416.00
```

This is the `main` code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUMBER_OF_STRING 6
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 50

void print_array(const char arr[][MAX_STRING_SIZE]);
void upper_comission (float [], char [5][50],char [5][50], int);
void lower_comission (float[], char [5][50],char [5][50], int);
void upper_netsalary (float [], char [5][50],char [5][50], int);
void lower_netsalary (float[], char [5][50],char [5][50], int);
float prom_sales(float[], int);

int main ()
{
    int numemployees, cont=0;
    float salary[50], salnet[50], sale[50], comission[50], ind=0, totalsales=0,totalsalary=0,totalsalnet=0, totalcomission=0, prom;
    char header[0], nom[5][50], lastname[5][50];

char arr[NUMBER_OF_STRING][MAX_STRING_SIZE] =
    { "Name",
      "salary",
      "Sale of the month",
      "Comission",
      "Net salary"
    };

    printf("Enter # of employees to consult: \n");
    scanf("%d",&numemployees);

     for(int i=0; i<numemployees; i++)
             {

                  printf("Enter employee's %d name : ",i+1);
                  scanf("%s", &nom[i]);

                  printf("Enter employee's %d last name : ",i+1);
                  scanf("%s", &lastname[i]);

                  printf("Enter employee's %d salary : ",i+1);
                  scanf("%f", &salary[i]);

                  printf("Enter sale of the month of the employee %d : ",i+1);
                  scanf("%f", &sale[i]);

                  system("cls");
            }

    print_array(arr); // function that shows the headers

    for(int i=0; i<=numemployees; i++)
    {

     if (sale[i] <= 1000)
        {
            comission[i]=sale[i] * 0.035;
            salnet[i]=salary[i]+comission[i];
        }

        if (sale [i] < 2000 || sale [i] > 1000)
        {
            comission[i]=sale[i] * 0.045;
            salnet[i]=salary[i]+comission[i];
        }

        if (sale [i] > 2000)
        {
            comission[i]=sale[i] * 0.054;
            salnet[i]=salary[i]+comission[i];
        }

            totalsales+=sale[i];
            totalsalary+=salary[i];
            totalcomission+=comission[i];
            totalsalnet+=salnet[i];

    printf("%25s %s %25.2f   %25.2f  %25.2f   %25.2f \n",nom[i],lastname[i], salary[i], sale[i], comission[i],salnet[i]);
    }


    printf("\t\tTotal %25.2f   %25.2f  %25.2f   %25.2f\n",totalsalary, totalsales, totalcomission, totalsalnet);


    upper_comission(comission, nom,lastname, numemployees);
    lower_comission(comission, nom,lastname, numemployees);
    upper_netsalary(salnet, nom,lastname, numemployees);
    lower_netsalary(salnet, nom,lastname, numemployees);
    prom=prom_sales(sale, numemployees);


    printf("\n");
    printf("Employees with sales upper than the prom (RD$%.2f) \n",prom);

    for (int i=0; i < numemployees; i++)
    {

    if (sale[i] > prom)
    {
        print_array(arr);
        printf("%25s %s %25.2f   %25.2f  %25.2f   %25.2f \n",nom[i],lastname[i], salary[i], sale[i], comission[i],salnet[i]);
    }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The functions:

```
void print_array(const char arr[NUMBER_OF_STRING][MAX_STRING_SIZE])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STRING; i++)
    {
        printf("%25s ", arr[i]);

        if (i == 5)
        {
            printf("%25s \n", arr[i]);
        }

    }
}
void upper_comission (float comission[],char nom[5][50],char lastname[5][50], int n)
{
    int i, nombre, apellido;
    float mayor;
    char name;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        mayor = comission[0];

        if (mayor < comission[i])
        {
            mayor = comission[i];
            nombre=i;
            apellido = i;
        }

    }
    printf("Employee with upper comission: %s %s %.2f \n",nom[nombre],lastname[apellido], mayor);
}

void lower_comission (float comission[],char nom[5][50],char lastname[5][50], int n)
{
    int i, nombre, apellido;
    float menor;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        menor = comission[0];

        if (menor > comission[i])
        {
            menor = comission[i];
            nombre=i;
            apellido=i;
        }

    }
    printf("Employee with lower comission: %s %s %.2f \n",nom[nombre],lastname[apellido], menor);
}

void upper_netsalary (float salnet[],char nom[5][50],char lastname[5][50], int n)
{

int i, nombre, apellido;
    float mayor;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        mayor = salnet[0];

        if (mayor < salnet[i])
        {
            mayor = salnet[i];
            nombre=i;
            apellido=i;
        }

    }
    printf("Employee with upper net salary: %s %s %.2f \n",nom[nombre],lastname[apellido], mayor);
}

void lower_netsalary (float salnet[], char nom[5][50],char lastname[5][50], int n)
{
int i, nombre, apellido;
    float menor;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        menor = salnet[0];

        if (menor > salnet[i])
        {
            menor = salnet[i];
            nombre=i;
            apellido=i;
        }

    }
    printf("Employee with lower net salary: %s %s %.2f \n",nom[nombre],lastname[apellido], menor);
}

float prom_sales(float sale[], int n)
{
    float prom=0;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        prom += sale[i];
    }


return prom/n;
}
```

My issues are these:

- The output shows the same name when it should be with the respective name of the comission/net salary **[fixed]**:

```
 Name                    salary                  Sale of the month                       Comission                       Net salary
marie gomez                                500.00                                  850.00                                   38.25                                  538.25
luca grus                                  856.00                                   80.00                                    3.60                                  859.60
Total                   1356.00                                                            930.00                                           41.85                                         1397.85
Employee with upper comission: luca grus 38.25
Employee with lower comission: luca grus 3.60
Employee with upper net salary: luca grus 859.60
Employee with lower net salary: luca grus 538.25

Employees with sales upper than the prom (RD$465.00)
Name                    salary                  Sale of the month                       Comission                       Net salary
marie gomez              500.00          850.00          38.25           538.25
```

- Before, the program printed the next codes like `the employee with upper comission`, etc. But now it doesn't show it.**[fixed]**
- The output should be well aligned, I tried with `printf("%25s");` but I didn't get the output like the one in the beginning.  **[fixed]**

I don't know If I am doing something wrong so please check it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `i<=numemployees`. you want `<` instead of `<=`. Also in `print_array` you are printing the last element twice.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Do you want `%-25s`, to get left-justification rather than the default right-justification?

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks, I did that but the array stars at 0 so when the user asks just for 2 employees, it asks for 3, that's why I changed that and put just  "<" instead of "<=".

Comment: But in the previous loop you have `i<numemployees;`.

Comment: @o11c left-justification

Comment: In order to get the names to print correctly, you have two choices: 1) combine the first and last names into a single string, and output with `printf("%-25s", fullname);` or 2) use the return value from `printf`. `printf` returns the number of characters that it printed. So `int count = printf("%s %s", nom[i], lastname[i]);` will set `count` to the number of characters printed. Then you can print spaces till you reach 25 characters.

Comment: @KamilCuk That's it. Thanks I fixed it :)

Comment: I think your maximum and minimum initial values (the lines where they are set to xxx[0]) should be moved outside the loop to just before it begins. Otherwise they are reset on every iteration and you lose the ones you've already tracked. Also your floating point constants should always have a decimal point in them (the zero is optional); otherwise they are integers and you get into trouble. "1 / 2" evaluates to (int) 0; "1. / 2." evaluates to (double) 0.5.

Comment: @eewanco can you please write where is it?

Comment: @aticboy In your upper_* and lower_* functions, which I presume calculate maximums and minimums, just after the `for` statement, you have lines such as `mayor = <something>[0]` and `menor = <something>[0]`. If you're calculating the minimums and maximums (I don't know your native language so I'm guessing based on my Latin skills at what the variables mean) these lines should be moved up out of the loop. As for the floating point constants, see your main() function starting at `if (sale[i] <= 1000)` -- the 1000 should be 1000.0 as well as the constants in the following lines.

Comment: @eewanco thanks, I fixed that. However, that function in the `nom[nombre]` print, when I compile it, shows the same name in all cases (upper, lower) but the `mayor` and `menor` works good.

Comment: @aticboy I'm not 100% sure this is your problem, but you are not initializing `nombre` and `apellido` to zero at the top, and you should, because if the first entry is a max or min, their values will be undefined. Automatic variables contain garbage by default. Your compiler _may_ be setting them to zero for you, but not all compilers will and it's a good practice to always initialize before referencing.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it.